# How to identify a specific exception thrown

Tags: c++, exception

I'm writing a class to process a stream which can throw multiple exceptions (not at once) upon certain fatal errors in the data it reads. In the driver program for that class, I have a try/catch block, in which I'd like to perform different behavior for the specific different exceptions that could occur.

e.g.:

```
try{
    functionWhichPerformsStreamProcessing(); // may throw exception at some point
}
catch (std::exception &exceptionWhichMustBeHandledDifferently){
    if ( <exception is some type> ){
        <code to handle>
    }
    else if ( <exception is some other type> ){
        <different code>
    }
    ...
}
```

I've considered:

1. checking against the exception's .what() string

   - seems very difficult to debug if the string is later changed
2. subclassing std::exception for every exception

   - seems like overkill when a new subclass would need to be created for every different exception
3. an exception with some form of error code, likely a string, which would *not* change even if the explanatory .what() is changed

   - I'd probably define preprocessor macros for these identifiers in a separate header to keep track of and make sure that doesn't ever change
   - this makes me think of the C-style error codes, though

[Frame-based Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) could be appropriate, but it's restricted to Windows and I want to make this code portable, and I actually have no clue what it's saying so it might not even be related anyway.

Because I'm processing a stream, I'd like to be able to break out of the processing immediately if such an error occurs, so I want to use exceptions here. There are probably ways to do it without exceptions, but the problem as it stands seems generic enough to be useful elsewhere, which is why I'm asking here.

Are there any best practices for such a situation?

Comment: Option (2) is the official way to do it.

Comment: Use subclassing. I use a macro DEFINE_EXCEPTION(exceptionName, what) that writes all the boilerplate for really simple exceptions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO the best way is to subclass std::exception. I'd usually write the subclasses except for very simple exceptions that I'd like to get out of the way quickly. In which case I'd use a macro..

But to have useful what text exceptions often need to accept more context about what went wrong which is why in the end most cases they are hand written.

Here is an example I once used:

```
#include <exception>

#define MAKE_EXCEPTION( v_class_name_, v_parent_name_, v_what_ )  \
 class v_class_name_                                              \
      : public  v_parent_name_ {                              \
      public:                                                 \
      inline virtual const char* what() const noexcept        \
            { return v_what_;}                        \
      }


MAKE_EXCEPTION(ZipFileException, std::exception, "ZipFileException: General Failure in ZipFile Operation");

MAKE_EXCEPTION(ZipFileInvalidFileException, ZipFileException, "ZipFileInvalidFileException: File is not a zipfile. Or File is corrupt");

MAKE_EXCEPTION(ZipFileEncryptionNotSupportedException, ZipFileException, "ZipFileEncryptionNotSupportedException: Can't open encrypted zip files");

MAKE_EXCEPTION(ZipFileCompressionMethodNotSupportedException, ZipFileException, "ZipFileCompressionMethodNotSupportedException: Zip file contains a compression method that is not supported");

MAKE_EXCEPTION(ZipFileOpenException, ZipFileException, "ZipFileOpenException: Failed to open the zipfile");

MAKE_EXCEPTION(ZipFileMultiPartNotSupportedException, ZipFileException, "ZipFileMultiPartNotSupportedException: Can't open multipart zip files");
```

...

So you can get an exception with just one line of code and using the hierarchy test for specific exceptions easily.

Comment: which is why in the end most exceptions classes are handwritten and not generated.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect multiple exceptions that you want to process, you can create your own exceptions subclassing std::exception, and then build a try-catch with multiple catch blocks like this:

```
try{
    functionWhichPerformsStreamProcessing(); 
}
catch (yourExceptionType &differentExceptionWhichMustBeHandledDifferently){
    //do stuff
}
catch (yourAnotherExceptionTYpe &yetAnotherExceptionWhichMustBeHandledDifferently){
    //do some additional stuff
}
catch (std::exception &exceptionWhichMustBeHandledDifferently){
    //do some different stuff
}
```

It enables you to skip all these if-else and makes the code cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: You should put most derived first... no?